# « Gelé comme une balle » : de quelle balle s'agit-il ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, québec, origine-ou-raison

> Gelé comme une [balle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/balle). ([Québec](http://www.laparlure.com/terme/etre-gele-comme-une-balle/))
>
> ---
>
> (a) Raide [comme une balle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/balle/1). (projectile ; argot : *de manière rapide, brutale, inattendue*)
> (b) [Être rond comme une balle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/balle/0). (objet sphérique ; argot : *complètement, avec excès*... ivre)

Le haut degré de l'effet de la substance psychotrope, par analogie ou métaphore. Et au lexique on a apparemment un sens qui s'apparente à celui de (b), *complètement, avec excès* mais sans référence au *rond* ; par ailleurs dans (a) on a le sens de projectile pour illustrer un emploi différent sans notion de sphère, sans *rond*...

---

- La locution québécoise s'appuie sur quel sens du mot *balle*, en quoi la *balle* exprime-t-elle le haut degré : est-ce
  une métamorphose de l'expression *être rond comme une balle* (*être gelé à la manière de quand on est rond comme une balle*) ; cette
  idée de rondeur englobant la comparaison survit-elle dans l'expression québécoise, est-ce on ou non à l'origine
  relié à l'idée de se *[rouler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouler) par/à terre* ou *sous la table* ?
- La collocation *comme une balle* connaît-elle un emploi indépendant
  des locutions lexicalisées et le cas échéant y a-t-il un sens « prédominant » ?

Comment: Gelé comme une balle de neige.

Comment: @BernardMassé Source ? Explication ? Un balle de neige n'est pas gelée, mais de neige ; il faut la garder dans les mains un moment ou il faut une neige très mouillée pour qu'on commence à avoir l'impression que c'est gelé. Ça n'explique pas pourquoi on utiliserait _geler_ pour être sous l'effet d'une substance ni pourquoi ça serait un haut degré de ça etc. Merci.

Comment: Ici en Suisse, c'est "givré comme une bille" qui a exactement le même sens.

Comment: @AlainD La _bille_ de l'expression, peut-elle être utilisée pour signifier _balle_ (de l'arme à feu) en Suisse ; selon vous comment et pourquoi une bille est-elle givrée ? Merci.

Comment: cc @Najib Idrissi Merci.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Cette réponse n’est pas documentée, et donc à prendre avec un grain de sel. Elle est le fruit d’une réflexion personnelle sur la question. Comme cette dernière est longtemps demeurée sans réponse, je présume qu’elle pourrait être intéressante, mais souhaiterais bien aussi qu’elle fît* balle de neige *et qu’un ou une autre y apporte une véritable réponse.*</sup>

---

Une balle (ou une bille) est ronde, et les sphères sont reconnues pour être instables sur des surfaces planes. La moindre perte de niveau ou de minimes courants d’air les fait bouger, d’une manière parfois désordonnée et peu prédictible.

L’expression *« avoir les pieds ronds »*, qui s’entend parfois chez moi, utilise cette particularité des sphères pour signifier une difficulté à se déplacer que la difficulté du terrain ne justifie pas ou pas entièrement. Parfois due à une position horizontale prolongée ayant apporté plus de sang qu’à l’habitude aux pieds, par exemple le sommeil de la nuit, on l’applique aussi lorsque les pieds s’emmêlent et que surviennent quelques pas de danse pour rattraper la perte d’équilibre s’ensuivant, surtout lorsque cela survient plus d’une fois. Il va de soi que la perte d’habileté provoquée par la consommation de psychotropes pourrait justifier l’usage de l’expression.

Une autre expression est encore plus près de celle étudiée ici : ***être rond*** *(être ivre d’alcool)*, qui peut se prolonger d’une comparaison à des objets courbes : *être rond comme une queue de pelle, comme une barrique,*  ***comme une balle***. Peut-être le caractère confus des gens ivres fut-il apparenté au comportement imprédictible et à l’état instable des objets courbes, dont la balle ou la bille sont plus ou moins des archétypes.

De l’alcool aux autres drogues récréatives, il y a certes une différence d’effets, mais en un cas comme dans l’autre, on observe un état de confusion et une perte plus ou moins grande des capacités physiques et cognitives, et on pourrait penser qu’il y a eu glissement de *« rond comme une balle »* à *« gelé/givré comme une balle »*.

Comment: Merci ! Je ne connaissais pas cette expression et l'association est intéressante. J'ai révisé au GPFC , on dit « à la balle » égal à « comme une balle, à toute vitesse » puis un autre exemple avec _en balle_ pour _très vite_ ; en utilisant ces associations, où c'est probablement la balle de l'arme à feu, j'ai une nouvelle hypothèse à l'effet que l'origine de l'expression repose sur un commentaire sur la faible tolérance de l'individu, ou sur une affirmation au sujet du fait qu'on atteigne l'état plus rapidement ou plus tôt que d'autres dans la même situation... Merci !

Comment: @dévastatordeconstuctors Un petit ajout, d'une idée qui s'est développée avec le temps et semble plus directement liée. ***Les pieds ronds*** est du domaine familial, je crois. Je ne l'entends jamais ailleurs que de ma famille proche, et bien que l'on ne nous reprenne pas lorsqu'elle est utilisée, je ne crois pas que les autres l'adoptent pour autant.